# React select drop down is going below react table pagination

Tags: react-select, react-table

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvaAp.jpg)[I tried to change the z-index of pagination to 0 it didnt't work]

Here is the link to my codesandbox:
Please check the last select dropdown, it's going behind pagination.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-chandrasekhar-uim6k

Comment: Please add a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code to help us solving this with you.

Comment: added the link to codesandbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React-select exposes a menuPortalTarget prop, that lets you portal the select menu to a dom node of your choosing.

To target body :

```
<ReactSelect
  options={[
    { value: "one", label: "One" },
    { value: "two", label: "Two" },
    { value: "three", label: "Three" }
  ]}
  menuPortalTarget={document.body}
/>
```

CodeSandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-cerf-wqtto

Comment: Great! thanks a lot, I was looking at this from last day, finally one line change 